not able to start Redhat CRC
I am not able to start the CRC container environment on my local machine. please help. below are the logs
$ crc start
INFO Using bundle path /home/ravi/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.17.0_amd64.crcbundle 
INFO Checking if running as non-root              
INFO Checking if running inside WSL2              
INFO Checking if crc-admin-helper executable is cached 
INFO Checking if running on a supported CPU architecture 
INFO Checking if crc executable symlink exists    
INFO Checking minimum RAM requirements            
INFO Check if Podman binary exists in: /home/ravi/.crc/bin/oc 
INFO Checking if Virtualization is enabled        
INFO Checking if KVM is enabled                   
INFO Checking if libvirt is installed             
INFO Checking if user is part of libvirt group    
INFO Checking if active user/process is currently part of the libvirt group 
INFO Checking if libvirt daemon is running        
INFO Checking if a supported libvirt version is installed 
INFO Checking if crc-driver-libvirt is installed  
INFO Checking crc daemon systemd socket units     
INFO Checking if AppArmor is configured           
INFO Checking if systemd-networkd is running      
INFO Checking if NetworkManager is installed      
INFO Checking if NetworkManager service is running 
INFO Checking if dnsmasq configurations file exist for NetworkManager 
INFO Checking if the systemd-resolved service is running 
INFO Checking if /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-crc.sh exists 
INFO Checking if libvirt 'crc' network is available 
INFO Checking if libvirt 'crc' network is active  
INFO Loading bundle: crc_libvirt_4.17.0_amd64...  
INFO Starting CRC VM for openshift 4.17.0...      
Error starting machine: Error in driver during machine start: virError(Code=9, Domain=10, Message='operation failed: Unable to find a satisfying virtiofsd')

I think, I need to install virtiofsd, but I need help.

downloaded virtiofsd from https://lib.rs/crates/virtiofsd and copied to /usr/bin. Not sure if that was what expected

Got resolved need to "sudo apt install virtiofsd"

Got resolved need to
sudo apt install virtiofsd
sudo apt install virt-manager

